# Zeros and poles of rational function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, solution-verification

Suppose we are given a rational function
$$f(s) = \frac{25s}{s^4+18s^3 +134s^2 +472s+680} $$ and we need to find the zeros and poles of the function.

Suppose $f(s) = \frac{a(s)}{b(s)}$, then $a(s) = 25s$ and $s = 0$ is a root of $a(s) =0$ and hence $0$ is a zero of $f(s)$. Again $b(s) = 0$ has roots at $s = -5 \pm3i$ and $s = -4\pm2i$, hence $-5 \pm3i$ and $-4\pm2i$ are poles of $f(s)$.

Is the solution correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: And first of all divide all by $\;5\;$ ...

Comment: Thank You @RobertIsrael

Comment: and @DonAntonio

Comment: You should make sure first that the fraction is in lowest terms.

Answer (score 1):

Just because $s = 0$ is a zero of $a(s)$ does not mean $s = 0$ is a zero of $f(s)$.  To be a zero, the numerator must be zero and the denominator not (otherwise, apply [l'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) to agonizingly cancel the common factor in $a$ and $b$).  Happily, $b(0) \neq 0$ and once you observe this fact, you have found all the zeroes of $f$ (and shown that it is a genuine zero of $f$).  (Example:  $z/z$ has a removable singularity at $z = 0$ and upon removal takes the value $1$.)

$f$ has a pole at $s$ if $b(s) = 0$ and $a(s) \neq 0$.  With the above modification, you would have already disposed of the possibility of common zeroes in $a$ and $b$, so every zero of $b$ is a pole, as you write.